# SQL Multiple Functions in One SQL File

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question regarding defining two functions back to back with PL/SQL. Below is the code I have:

```
create or replace procedure test2(mynum in integer, retnum out integer)
as
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(mynum + 1);
    retnum := 1000;
end;



create or replace procedure test3(mynum in integer, retnum out integer)
as
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(mynum + 1);
    retnum := 1000;
end;
```

When I run it I get the following error, but when I create the functions separately I do not. Am I missing some keyword to separate the two declarations?

```
Procedure TEST2 compiled
```

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

10/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" 
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: https://rextester.com/LZFQFA22750 check the link i ran it and works properly

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using SQLPlus as your database client. Add a `/` on a line by itself after the `END;` for each procedure. Best of luck.

Comment: You need a delimiter between the two functions. As @BobJarvis said, it should be a `/`.

Answer (score 4):

After every PL/SQL statement you should properly end it by adding `/` on a separate line as this is the "master delimiter".

Try to save your script as this:

```
create or replace procedure test2(mynum in integer, retnum out integer)
as
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(mynum + 1);
    retnum := 1000;
end;
/

create or replace procedure test3(mynum in integer, retnum out integer)
as
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(mynum + 1);
    retnum := 1000;
end;
/
```